# Notification PendingIntent hard bug (or really simple one)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to debug this for **ages** now and I just can't seem to find the problem:

I have a broadcast receiver, which receives the broadcast successfully.
The notification has two actions ("buttons"):

```
firstIntent = null; 
secondIntent = null;

firstPendingIntent = null; //first "button" to join with the first intent
secondPendingIntent = null; //second "button" to join with the second intent

if(boolean){

//relevant

firstIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationFunctions.class).putExtra("action", "do_this");
secondIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationFunctions.class).putExtra("action", "do_that");

}else{

firstIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationFunctions.class).putExtra("action", "do_another_this");
secondIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationFunctions.class).putExtra("action", "do_another_that");

}

firstPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, firstIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

secondPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, secondIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                    .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                                    .setContentText(notification_text)
                                    .setTicker("Notification!")
                                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
.addAction(R.drawable.abc_cab_background_top_holo_light, first_option, firstPendingIntent)
.addAction(R.drawable.abc_cab_background_top_holo_dark, second_option, secondPendingIntent)
                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                                    .build();
```

Whenever I debug in the **broadcastReceiver**, for some reason, action from **extras** always logs "do_that", even if I click the first or second button of the notification. Any reason for this? I cant really seem to understand why.

```
public class NotificationFunctions extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean feedback;

        String action = intent.getExtras().getString("action");

        Log.wtf("...", action); //logs do_that

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any reason for this?

Because `firstPendingIntent == secondPendingIntent`.

If there already is a `PendingIntent` matching your request, `getBroadcast()` returns the existing `PendingIntent`. `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` says to replace the extras in the `Intent` wrapped inside the `PendingIntent`.

In one of your two `getBroadcast()` calls, replace `0` with some other number, to get distinct `PendingIntent` objects.

Also, I recommend that you replace `getBaseContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` with `this`. Only use `getBaseContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` when you know **precisely why** you are using them.

Comment: <3. Can you just explain why use `this`instead of getBaseContext or getApplicationContext?

Comment: @RichardNorton: I did "just explain". For example, `getBaseContext()` is largely undocumented. And, it is a method on `Activity`, which *is* a `Context`. Why would you use an undocumented method returning some `Context` that you don't know what it is, when you already have a `Context` to use? Beyond that, I would recommend [Dave Smith's blog post](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) on the roles of different sources of `Context`.